# HornetQ lost its all topics

Tags: hornetq

I would like to use hornetQ server as stand-alone without JNDI.
I started hornetQ server and added 10 topics with jconsole.
Then I made a test that restart hornetQ server in a loop.
At the abour 10th restart hornetQ server lost all the topics it had.

(I'm using hornetQ client with spring)

Any idea what cause hornetQ to lost the topics? How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to provide a testcase showing it's either a bug or a configuration mistake you made. It's hard to say what's going on.

There was a recent bug fix about deleting JMS destinations though. I'm not sure it would be related to this.